# Zend Framework - ACL Authentication

Tags: zend-framework, authentication, acl

i create simple Zend authentication. Everything is working fine... while in my Bootstrap.php i add line `$objFront->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl(), 1);`.

My library/My/Controller/Plugin/Acl.php file looks

```
    <?php
// library/My/Controller/Plugin/ACL.php
class My_Controller_Plugin_ACL extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    protected $_defaultRole = 'guest';

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request){
        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $acl = new My_Acl();
        $mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('mysession');

        if($auth->hasIdentity()) {
            $user = $auth->getIdentity();
            if(!$acl->isAllowed($user->role, $request->getControllerName() . '::' . $request->getActionName())) {
                $mysession->destination_url = $request->getPathInfo();

                return Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector')->setGotoUrl('auth/noauth');
            }
        } else {
            if(!$acl->isAllowed($this->_defaultRole, $request->getControllerName() . '::' . $request->getActionName())) {
                $mysession->destination_url = $request->getPathInfo();

                return Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('redirector')->setGotoUrl('auth/login');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

my library/My/Acl.php file looks

```
<?php
// library/My/Acl.php
class My_Acl extends Zend_Acl
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // Add a new role called "guest"
        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
        // Add a role called user, which inherits from guest
        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('user'), 'guest');
        // Add a role called admin, which inherits from user
        $this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('admin'), 'user');
 
        // Add some resources in the form controller::action
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('error::error'));
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::login'));
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('auth::logout'));
        $this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('index::index'));
 
        // Allow guests to see the error, login and index pages
        $this->allow('guest', 'error::error');
        $this->allow('guest', 'auth::login');
        $this->allow('guest', 'index::index');
        // Allow users to access logout and the index action from the user controller
        $this->allow('user', 'auth::logout');
        $this->allow('user', 'user::index');
        // Allow admin to access admin controller, index action
        $this->allow('user', 'admin::index');
 
        // You will add here roles, resources and authorization specific to your application, the above are some examples
    }
}
```

Bootstrap.php file

```
<?php
require_once '../library/Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::registerAutoload();
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    protected function _initSession(){
        Zend_Session::start();
    }

    protected function _initPlugins()
    {
        $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $autoloader->registerNamespace('My_');

        $objFront = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        // $objFront->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl(), 1);
        return $objFront;
    }
}
```

I've no idea where is the problem. Can someone check my code and give me advice?

Thank You.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the commented line that you did

```
// $objFront->registerPlugin(new My_Controller_Plugin_Acl(), 1);
```

The name of the class is

```
class My_Controller_Plugin_ACL
```

notice the uppercases ACL not Acl like in the commented code of yours :)
And please next time ask your question. And tell us what is the problem :)